# Xrandr issues in Arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, kde, xrandr, amdgpu

I am running Arch Linux with KDE Plasma as my DE on a Lenovo Z16 laptop with AMD CPU and Radeon RX 6500M dedicated graphics card.

Up until kernel version 6.4.12 I could use xrandr to change my monitor resolution with no issues. However from kernel 6.5.2 onwards, using xrandr to change resolution to anything apart from my monitor's native one (3840x2400) results in a black screen.

Any ideas on how I can go about debugging this?